# Combination of RIGHT CTRL, RIGHT SHIFT and an ARROW key not repeating

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

This is perhaps my first post ever, asking for help on a Windows related problem and I already did all I could to resolve the problem myself but to no avail.

OS: Windows 10.0
Machine: Dell Inspiron 5559 (it's new so I know there is nothing wrong with the hardware)

Here is the predicament I am faced with:

When I use a combination of the RIGHT <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, RIGHT <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and an ARROW-KEY to let's say select text in a Word/Google document, the combination works once but does not repeat itself if I keep holding down the keys (it used to on my last laptop which had Windows 7 installed on it).

I have already checked the Ease of Access Center. Sticky, Toggle and Filter keys are all OFF.

I have disabled the Intel HD Graphics hotkeys.

I have researched probably about 20 articles but nothing.

Guys, this is very important for me to fix because I work with text a LOTTTT and have to use this combination very frequently. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

PS: LEFT <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, LEFT <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and RIGHT (or LEFT) ARROW-KEYS combination still works and it repeats if I press and hold those keys.
But for whatever odd reason, RIGHT <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, RIGHT <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and RIGHT (or LEFT) ARROW-KEYS combination is not repeating.

Answer (score 0):

As a point of comparison: my Samsung Windows 10 laptop has the Intel HD Graphics 4000, but I am not running the Intel Graphics Toolbox (just the drivers).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd><</kbd> and …<kbd>></kbd> auto-repeat fine for me - I use them all the time too!
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd><</kbd>, …<kbd>></kbd>, …<kbd>^</kbd> and … <kbd>v</kbd> are the rotate commands for me.

My suggestion? Remove the Intel Graphics Toolbox thingy (it doesn't do any more than native Windows does anyway...) and try again. I know you say you've disabled the hotkey features - but who knows if it really has?

Comment: I tried that just now but it did not work for me John but thank you for responding nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact thing happening on my PC. It was due to the *"Intro"* key of the numeric keypad being stuck. Release it and problem gone.

You can easily reproduce the issue by maintaining that key pressed on purpose.